# someConstant?.isKindOfClass(SomeClassType) always evaluates to true

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to determine different action depending upon the type of the rvc:

```
 let rvc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window?.rootViewController
 if rvc?.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController)
 {
     push the view controller
 }
 else
 {
     present the view controller
 }
```

However when I execute this with a storyboard where the initial view controller is not a UINavigationController, just a descendant of UIViewController then the first branch of the if statement is executing.

UPDATE: The problem actually is with the syntax because in the following code each if statement will evaluate to true:

```
if rvc?.isKindOfClass(UIViewController)
{
    println("UIViewController")
}
if rvc?.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController)
{
    println("nav controller")
}
if rvc?.isKindOfClass(NSNotification)
{
    println("should not get here")
}
if rvc?.isKindOfClass(put whatever you want here)
{
    println("should not get here")
}
```

Therefore there must be a problem with the syntax/semantic of rvc?.isKindOfClass but what is incorrect with that?

Comment: are you sure this is your syntax ? you're saying : "if rvc is a NavigationController, build another nativationController with rvc as it's root" ... isn't the if - logic the wrong way around here ?

Comment: `if rvc is? UINavigationController`

Comment: Its not the type of rvc, its a problem with the fact that rvc?.isKindOfClass always evaluates to true. See updated question.

Comment: Thanks for downvote Mr. annoymous. WHat's the problem then if you know so much you feel this merits a downvote? Why not answer the question.

Comment: Marvellous, isn't it? He down voted my input too, but didn't give a better answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax seems valid. This works in Playground:

```
class MyNavC: UINavigationController {    
}

let v = MyNavC(navigationBarClass: nil, toolbarClass: nil)
let v1 = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

let b = v.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) // true
let b1 = v1.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) // false
```

...but those aren't optionals (nor are allowed to be).

Trying your code in an actual app with the optionals necessary for *your* assignment:

`let rvc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window?.rootViewController`

you are correct,

`if rvc?.isKindOfClass(xxxAnyClassxx) {`

*always* evaluates true. However, using

`if rvc!.isKindOfClass(...) {`

gives the correct result.

Comment: There is indeed a problem with the syntax, see the updated question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I appreciate it. Must be something to do with the ? in either the if line or the let line?

Comment: Well certainly the difference between what you are doing and what I got working is mine were not optional...

Comment: @Sausages - Got it! Use `rvc!` rather than `rvc?`

Comment: Cool. thanks. Do you know the reason why there is a difference?

Comment: When you use `?.method` (i.e., option chaining), the result of that method is encapsulated in a Optional. That's the whole point. Testing the logical value of an Optional in an if statement will return true if the Optional contains something, and false if it's nil -- it does NOT look at what the value inside the Optional is. In this case, it's that contained value that you actually want to check.

Comment: @WesCampaigne: that should be an answer

Comment: this is not the answer... Wes Capaigne got it right

Comment: I agree. Mine is only a solution, Wes's has the insight and the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to Grimxn's answer (and in response to the question of the difference between `if rvc?.isKindOfClass(xxxAnyClassxx) {` and `if rvc!.isKindOfClass(...) {`):

When you use `?.method` (i.e., option chaining), the result of that method is encapsulated in a Optional. That's the whole point; the final result of an option chain will either be `.Some(the result of the last method in the chain)` or `nil` if any point in the chain resulted in `nil`.

Testing the logical value of an `Optional` in an `if` statement will return `true` if the `Optional` contains something (i.e., its value is `.Some(...)`), and `false` if it's `nil` -- it does NOT look at what the value inside the `Optional` is. In this case, it's that contained value that you actually want to check.